# discrepancy between string's maximum size and its real capacity in c++

Tags: c++, string

I would like to ask a question regarding string in C++.

I wrote some codes to compare suffix and prefix calculated from string as below.

```
 string s;
 int num = 0;

       for(int i = 1; i <s.size(); i++)
        {
            string prefix = s.substr(0,s.size()-i);
            string suffix = s.substr(i,s.size()-i);
            cout <<"prefix : "<<prefix<<" suffix : "<<suffix<<endl;
            if(prefix==suffix){
                num = prefix.size();
                break;
            }
        }
```

this codes find the maximum length of string that can be prefix and suffix of the original string.

when I inputted very large size of string (approximately length of 1Mb), then my 
compiler alerted me that my string will be cut because of its size. However, when I checked the string size by s.max_size(), I found that it returned the very big number ( more than 1Mb).

So, my question is as below.

1. How to handle very large size of string (up to 1Mb) ?
   (assume that string container must be used.)
2. Is there any more efficient way to find the maximum length of string compared to my codes above?

Comment: What was your method of input?

Comment: Your *compiler* certainly didn't alert you to anything about your input. Please try to relate more accurately what happened. If necessary use a screenshot.

Comment: Secondly, on any modern general computer 1 MB is a teeny tiny little string. It's not large, not to mention very large. It's about one ten thousandth of the RAM in this laptop I'm writing on, for example.

Comment: Regarding your question #2, your algorithm has quadratic time. To learn about this, I suggest you figure out why. After you have understood why it has quadratic time, it should not be difficult to reduce that to linear.

Comment: Shouldn't be easier to compare the characters at the extremes of the string, looping to the center of the string and breaking if two different chars are found?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thanks for your comment. the problems is the usage of substr inside of the for loop. This caused the quadratic time complexity. However, I didn't get the idea of how to reduce the above to linear solution. can you give me a hint?

Comment: string may be stored on the stack, so you have a limited size of it. You could use pointer to char to handle as much data as RAM allows you. If you use the char* you will know for sure how much memory you have alocated to it, so you wil know it size simply. And you will be able to iterate untill the '\0' character is found with a for instruction, which is pretty well from performance point of  view in c++ even for log loops.